# Replace string based on array element

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0, replace

I have a array with some value and also having some parameter string.I have placed both below.
I would like to replace the parameter string based on array element. Please help me to do thi.

```
string[] arrayval = {"Type:1","Action:doit","Message:hai"};

string Param = "Type:[Type]#Action:[Action]#Message:[Message]#OutMsg:[OutMsg]#@RetVal:[RetVal]";

My Expected Output 


string Param = "Type:1#Action:doit#Message:hai#OutMsg:[OutMsg]#@RetVal:[RetVal]";
```

Comment: Why don't you use dictionary instead of an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not tested and some checks should be added but, see in version of @Ulugbek Umirov :)

```
var pattern = @"\[(.*?)\]";
var matches = Regex.Matches(Param, pattern);

foreach (Match m in matches) {
    var inb = "[" + m.Groups[1] + "]";
    var results = arrayval.Select (s  => s.Split(':'))
                          .FindAll(ss => ss[0] == m.Groups[1])
                          .Select (ss => ss[1]);
    Param = Param.Replace(inb, results[0]);
}
```

btw... a bit shorter version of @Ulugbek Umirov which should work just fine :)

```
Param = Regex.Replace(Param, @"\[(.+?)\]", m =>
    arrayval.Select(s => s.Split(new[] { ':' }, 2))
            .Where (p => p.Length == 2)
            .Where (p => p[0] == m.Groups[1].Value)
            .Select(p => p[1])
            .FirstOrDefault() ?? m.Value);
```

**Update for replace with 0 if not exists:**

```
Param = Regex.Replace(Param, @"\[(.+?)\]", m =>
    arrayval.Select(s => s.Split(new[] { ':' }, 2))
            .Where (p => p.Length == 2)
            .Where (p => p[0] == m.Groups[1].Value)
            .Select(p => p[1])
            .FirstOrDefault() ?? "0");
```

Comment: @Neel as in question declared

Comment: why to use so many line of codes when you can do the samething in just 2 lines?

Comment: Please see my updated question. i need the same output while am giving the some strings in param.

Comment: @user3085540 isn't it already passed there with `?? m.Value` ?

Comment: @Heather No, FirstOrDefault() would return null, and you try to get [1] from it.

Comment: @Heather I need a small change in my question Action:*[Action] instead of old one. If action present in arrayval means i need the above output. Otherwise i need the below output  "Type:1#Action:0#Message:hai#OutMsg:[OutMsg]#@RetVal:[RetVal]";

Comment: @user3085540 replace with 0 if not found? for all or only for action?

Comment: Only if the array element not exists

Comment: If action or other does not exists in array means, replace that with 0.

Comment: @user3085540 then just `?? "0"` instead of providing old value there

Answer (score 3):

not very neat. But based on what information you have given. Following should work.

```
string[] arrayval = { "Type:1", "Action:doit", "Message:hai" };
string Param = string.Format("Type:{0}#Action:{1}#Message:{2}", arrayval[0].Split(':')[1], arrayval[1].Split(':')[1], arrayval[2].Split(':')[1]);
```

**OutPut:**
    Type:1#Action:doit#Message:hai

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified version of @Heather

```
Param = Regex.Replace(Param, @"\[(.+?)\]", m =>
{
    string paramName = m.Groups[1].Value;
    string paramValue = arrayval.Select(s => s.Split(new[] { ':' }, 2))
                                .Where(p => p.Length == 2)
                                .Where(p => p[0] == paramName)
                                .Select(p => p[1])
                                .FirstOrDefault();
    return paramValue ?? m.Value;
});
```

Comment: I need a small change in my question Action:*[Action] instead of old one. If action present in arrayval means i need the above output. Otherwise i need the below output "Type:1#Action:0#Message:hai#OutMsg:[OutMsg]#@RetVal:[RetVal]";

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..i have tested it in VS 2012

```
string[] arrayval = { "Type:1", "Action:doit", "Message:hai" };

string Param = "Type: " + arrayval[0].Split(Convert.ToChar(":"))[1] + "#Action: " + arrayval[1].Split(Convert.ToChar(":"))[1] + "#Message: " + arrayval[2].Split(Convert.ToChar(":"))[1];
```

Output :-

```
Type: 1#Action: doit#Message: hai
```